# System.Linq: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, linq

There is a old Asp.Net WebSite Project, opened in VS 2015 which targeting a 4.0 FrameWork Version, when I am trying to build it it gives me below error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
>    `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)` and `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)`

which both method signature looks exactly identical.

Here it code from the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // Gray out
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; // Gray out
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.UI; // Gray out

public class UrlRoute
{

  public static string RegisterRoutes(string routes)
  {
    string MainUrl = routes;
    string result = "";
    if (MainUrl.Contains('\\')==true)
    {
      result = "CMS"
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Project Properties:

[image: Reference]

Framework Details:

[image: FrameWork Details]

I tried solution from SO but none of them worked [delete bin folder, check unresolved references], don't understand the reason behind the error!

**EDIT:**

**Same is happening for `Last()` and all that extension method from `System.Linq`:**

> Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Last(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Last(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'

*Will love to share any other configuration/code if required.*

Comment: Have you considered using the instance method `MainUrl.Contains("\\")` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: btw: `== true` is redundant, `Contains` already returns a `bool`

Comment: @GabrielLuci Good point, just got the TFS link, I just downloaded and builded- then there is a missing reference of LINQ so I added by using NuGet.

Comment: You have two references to `System.Linq`. Remove one of them.

Comment: @mjwills I deleted `System.Linq` from bin folder and errors are just fade away + build successful! Is it needs to be done?

Comment: Well, if it worked then apparently it did need to be done.

Comment: @mjwills Special thanks!

Comment: You said you "deleted the bin folder", which should have fixed this (if deleting one DLL fixed it). So I'm curious if it will end up putting it back from somewhere.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Took backup!

Comment: @mjwills Can you help me with this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020793/asp-net-core-download-ssrs-reports-in-pdf-format-on-client-browser-by-its-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely referencing two versions of `System.Linq.dll`. Project should use version from GAC, not local copy from BIN.

Try to find and remove explicit reference to `System.Linq.dll` in your C# project.

P.S. And if you have multiple projects in the solution, make sure they all target same version of .NET Framework.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Glad it worked. In case subsequent build puts `System.Linq.dll` back the application folder, then you need to check/clean project references.

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020793/asp-net-core-download-ssrs-reports-in-pdf-format-on-client-browser-by-its-url