# Asp.Net Core: Download SSRS reports in PDF format on client browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reporting-services

I have one SSRS report URL which if I enter that URL in the browser then it shows the SSRS report with Print and Save option like:

[image]

Which works fine on the browser.

What I want, there is one button on `.cshtml` page so by clicking on that button I need to download the report on client browser.

URL: http://xyz/ReportS/report/UAT/SampleReport_V1?Srno=X123

What I tried:

by setting `&rs:Format=PDF` and made a HTTP Request from Asp.Net Core Application but it generated PDF but in corrupt format.

Code:

```
public void Download_SSRSInPDF()
{
    string URL = "http://xyz/ReportS/report/UAT/SampleReport_V1";
    string Command = "Render";
    string Format = "PDF";
    URL = URL + "?SrNo=X123&rs:Command=" + Command + "&rs:Format=" + Format;
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest Req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);

    Req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    Req.Method = "GET";
    string path = @"E:\New folder\Test.pdf";
    System.Net.WebResponse objResponse = Req.GetResponse();
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    System.IO.Stream stream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);

    while (len > 0)
    {
        fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
        len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
    }
    stream.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

How to do it in Asp.Net Core?

**EDIT:**:

I have that asmx url of my report:

```
http://server-name/ReportServer/reportexecution2005.asmx
```

But unable to proceed with this, can someone points me towards documentation?

Comment: In what way is it corrupt?

Comment: @mjwills its say's failed to load a file..the way I am trying that is not correct i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a simple URL to download the report in PDF format, don't add parameters to the web portal URL but add them to an URL that points to the web service:

```
string URL = "http://xyz/reportserver/?/UAT/SampleReport_V1";
string Command = "Render";
string Format = "PDF";
URL = URL + "&SrNo=X123&rs:Command=" + Command + "&rs:Format=" + Format;
```

Comment: @PrashantPimpale: It's not the same code. I replaced `ReportS/report` by `reportserver`, which is the default name of the web service. Also, I inserted the question mark there, because the path to the report should be the first parameter of the web service URL. At last, I replaced your question mark (in the last line of the snippet to be replaced) by an ampersand (`&`). What comes out when you replace your 4 lines by mine?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale: The complete URL should look like this:

`http://xyz/reportserver/?/UAT/SampleReport_V1&SrNo=X123&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF`, for testing, paste it in your browser.

Comment: Yup, its generating the expected PDF! Why we have used that `?`

Comment: + as mentioned by Nick it gives me error when I try that URL in the another PC (Who don't have access to the SSRS report to view), how do I pass some default credentials?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale The `?` is the separator between the web service URL and everything that is "parameters" for the request. As for the credentials: You are passing the "DefaultCredentials". If those aren't sufficient to access the report and you want to bypass the permissions granted to the user, just fill the `Req.Credentials` with credentials that allow access to the report.

Comment: Okay, will try and let you know

Comment: Done! Now the file has generated successully in the specified folder! Just one more thing if you can help, it is possible to generated the file on the browser itself, instead of generating in folder?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Great to hear that. To display the PDF in the browser, I suggest to use some `Response.Redirect` to the generated URL. You might find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/response-redirect-to-new-window) (meaning that the user must be permitted to see the report).

Comment: In asp.net we use `Response.Write()` and `Response.Clear()` which will generate a file on the client browser by using ByteArray, so just want to know if that is possible in asp.net core with about code

Comment: Hi, I need to write that returned bytes on the client's browser

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40488246) will help you.

Comment: I tried but none of those worked..i m stuck.. Need your help..i have also posted a new question for this

Answer (score 2):

You're better off doing this using the supported ReportExecution2005.asmx endpoint with something like WCF, instead of trying to use HTTP web request to impersonate a user interaction in a browser.

Once you've got it setup, there are Render methods on the report execution instance that make it really easy to get the report as a PDF.

Comment: Yes...I got the asmx URL..but unable to proceed from that. Will it work in Core?

Comment: Or you can guide me towards document? Will really appreciate!

Comment: yes tried with asmx URL but there are some methods signature got changed

Answer (score 1):

you are converting to `pdf` with default converter of code. we do not follow this method to convert reports in to `pdf`. If you wanna ask more option which is lengthy but not tough to do. You can use [WKHTMLtopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) method to convert your html in to `pdf`. it is easy to use. I am not saying that the method you are using is wrong. but we need to use latest technologies. `Asp.netcore`  is working fine with `wkhtmltopdf` to convert html page in to pdf.